# Is using HMAC signature as a long-term password secure?

Tags: authentication, authenticated-encryption, pbkdf, kbkdf

I'm considering implementing an authentication service without storing users' passwords/hash.

I want to use a key derivation function with a corresponding `username` and a `master secret key` to calculate the `password` of the user(user is actually a service). Then deliver the derived password to each user(service).

Something like using `HMAC(secret_master_key, username)` or `PBKDF2(HMAC(secret_master_key, username))` as the long-term password for user. Or maybe some other algorithm should be more suitable for this scenario?

Is this way secure cryptographically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/219613/86735). See this [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/403350)

Comment: @kelalaka I think this topic is more applicable here. Could I just close the topic on security site and keep this topic?

Comment: Actually I'd recommend against deletion for now given that the comments there may still hold useful information for context. Instead you could flag your post as "recommend closure" so it will be placed into the close-vote review queue.

Comment: FYI, an HMAC is not a signature.  In cryptography, a signature is a _public-key_ concept which is verifiable by _anyone_ who has the public key—not just the signer who has the private key.  But an HMAC, as a _symmetric_ authenticator, is verifiable only by the parties who can create the HMAC too, and _vice versa_.  That said, it's not the _MAC_ property of HMAC you're after; rather, it's the _PRF_ property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your `master secret key` is generated properly and protected properly, this should be fine. HMAC is widely believed to be a pseudorandom function. So, the output (i.e. the password = `PRF(secret_master_key, username)`) should be pseudorandom and has good entropy.

Comment: Thanks! that's good news. I realized I could also use PBKDF2(secret_master_key+username) directly, I think PBKDF2 must be a PRF too. So if there's already underlay PBKDF2 function(I'm actually dealing with kerberos, which already have a PBKDF2 inside), do I still need HMAC? Or I could directly use master_key+username as password?

Comment: If you do so, you might have to record a salt for each username if you want to regenerate the passwords. When invoking PBKDF2(password, salt, iter_count, keylength), internally PBKDF2 will invoke a PRF uses the argument `password` as the PRF key and a value derived from `salt` as the PRF input (in the first iteration, later iterations uses the previous iteration's output). The PRF can be an HMAC. If you use `secret_master_key` as the `password` argument and `username` as the salt argument to PBKDF2, and chooses a good HMAC (HMAC-SHA2) then it should be fine and don't need to record the salts.

Comment: Make sure you make `username` case insensitive and encode it as an octet string before feeding it to PBKDF2.